# Import sql script in Android application

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm developing an android application which use SQLite database. 
The question is: can I import an external script (i.e. script.sql) which can upgrade the structure of SLQLite database in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not, SQLiteDatabase class has "rawQuery" method which can perfrom any valid sql commands. So you only need to create the database, read your script from file and feed it to SQLiteDatabase instance